# In akka-actor-typed, what is the difference between Behaviors.setup and Behaviors.receive?

Tags: akka, akka-typed

Reading the [Akka 2.6.10 API Docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6.10/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Behaviors$.html), the difference between `akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.setup` and `akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.receive` ought to have been immediately clear to me. But it wasn't.

The [documentation site](https://akka.io/docs) provides some excellent examples, but it still took me a lot of pondering to catch on to the intended purpose for each function, which was never really stated explicitly.

In the hope of saving future Akka (Typed) newbies some time, I will try to clarify the differences between these behavior-defining functions. This is basic stuff, but it's important for understanding the rest.

Answer (score 8):

#### akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.setup

`Behaviors.setup` defines behavior that ***does not wait to receive a message*** before executing. It simply executes its body immediately after an actor is spawned from it.

You must return a `Behavior[T]` from it, which *might* be a message-handling behavior. To do this, you would likely use `Behaviors.receive` or `Behaviors.receiveMessage`. (Or else `Behaviors.stopped`, if the actor is only required to do its work once once, and then disappear.)

Because it executes without waiting, `Behaviors.setup` is often used to define the behavior for the first actor in your system. Its initial behavior will likely be responsible for spawning the next brood of actors that your program will need, before adopting a new, message-handling behavior.

#### akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.receive

`Behaviors.receive` defines ***message-handling behavior***. You pass it a function that has parameters for both the actor context, and an argument containing the message. Actors created from this behavior will *do nothing* until they receive a message of a type that this behavior can handle.

Comment: Can you clarify "which _might_ be a message-handling behavior"?

Comment: @steddy You must return a Behavior[T] that will determine what the Behaviors.setup actor will do once it has finished its setup work.

With Behaviors.receive or Behaviors.receiveMessage, you can define a new behavior for the actor, allowing it to receive messages and take more actions.

But you don't have to do that. You could also decide that this actor's work is done, and return Behaviors.stopped, which will not handle any more messages.

Comment: Almost out of topic, but is it legal to return Behaviors.setup as a new behavior, either after a Behaviors.setup or Behaviors.receive? Can you devise a scenario where this would make sense?

Comment: @steddy Take a look at paragraph 2 of [the current API docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Behaviors$.html#setup[T](factory:akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.ActorContext[T]=%3Eakka.actor.typed.Behavior[T]):akka.actor.typed.Behavior[T]) for the answer to this question. The docs seem to have improved a lot since I wrote the original post.